# How do I navigate the org-mode clock history menu?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

No matter what I try, I can't make `(org-clock-in-last)` work properly with its menu.

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Clocking-commands.html) says:

> `C-c C-x C-x     (org-clock-in-last)`
>
> Reclock the last clocked task. With one C-u prefix argument, select the task from the clock history. With two C-u prefixes, force continuous clocking by starting the clock when the last clock stopped.

The menu it produces with `C-u C-c C-x C-x` looks like this:

[image: recent tasks]

Yet hitting 1, 2, or 3 on my keyboard just clocks me into the current heading I'm on. Running this same command on an empty buffer in `org-mode` confirms that the selector is ignoring the menu:

```
Select task for clocking:
byte-code: Before first headline at position 2123 in buffer *scratch* [2 times]
```

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in the source of org-mode that has been resolved in master: http://orgmode.org/w/org-mode.git?p=org-mode.git;a=commit;h=a752684bf0368ddea1f6480157e770c0dd57b7a5

Comment: Wow, current! I'll test later when I have time to rebuild. Thanks.